# Behat + Laravel. Scenario failing as redirect seems to not happen

Tags: php, laravel, behat, laravel-5

I'm trying to get to grips with using Behat and Laravel 5. I have a simple scenario that involves creating a post:

```
Scenario: Post Creation
  Given I have an account "john" "john@example.com"
  When I create a post "Example Post" "Example Content"
  Then I should see a post "Example Post"
```

In my feature context I defined the "creating" and "seeing" a post as follows:

```
/**
 * @When I create a post :title :content
 * @param $title string
 * @param $content string
 */
public function iCreateAPost($title, $content)
{
    $this->visit('admin/posts/create');
    $this->fillField('title', $title);
    $this->fillField('slug', \Str::slug($title));
    $this->fillField('content', $content);
    $this->pressButton('Create Post');
    $this->printCurrentUrl();

}

/**
 * @Then I should see a post :title
 * @param $title
 */
public function iShouldSeeAPost($title)
{
    $this->visit('admin/posts');
    $this->printCurrentUrl();
    $this->assertPageContainsText($title);
}
```

If I follow these steps myself through the browser everything works fine. However my `iShouldSeeAPost` test fails.

Upon further inspection the `admin/posts` page is visited but doesn't contain the newly added post. I worked backwards and found that at the end of the `iCreateAPost` method the current url is the one that corresponds to the `store` method of my controller, when in reality the controller redirects to the `admin/posts/edit` page. So something must be failing just after the `pressButton('Create Post')` action.

How can I debug this? I can't seem to find any better way to view the flow of requests and responses other the `printLastResponse` which isn't much use. I don't think it's a validation problem and my other feature tests work suggesting it's not a database issue.

For reference here is the test output:

```
  Scenario: Post Creation                                 # features/posts.feature:6
    Given I have an account "john" "john@example.com"     # FeatureContext::iHaveAnAccount()
    When I create a post "Example Post" "Example Content" # FeatureContext::iCreateAPost()
      │ http://localhost/admin/posts/store
    Then I should see a post "Example Post"               # FeatureContext::iShouldSeeAPost()
      │ http://localhost/admin/posts
      The text "Example Post" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ResponseTextException)

--- Failed scenarios:

    features/posts.feature:6

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (2 passed, 1 failed)
```

**Update**

Still no luck with this. This is testing the most basic CRUD task and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the store method on the controller. I'm using Laravel's dependency injection for validating the request and storing the post.

```
public function store(Post $post, CreatePostRequest $request)
{
    $post = $post->create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('admin.posts.edit', [$post->id])
        ->with(['alert' => 'Post saved', 'alert-class' => 'success']);
}
```

When I use `$this->printLastResponse();` in my test I seem to get very little output, usually just the url. It seems the store method on the controller is not working as the 
`iShouldSeeAPost()` does infact output the html of the index page but the post has not been stored.

As I say, if I manually carry out the test it works as expected.

relevant files:

https://github.com/harrygr/Creuset/blob/master/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php
https://github.com/harrygr/Creuset/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/PostsController.php
https://github.com/harrygr/Creuset/blob/master/app/Http/Requests/CreatePostRequest.php

Comment: I had a problem with the Str class earlier today with laravel 5, can you confirm that it works for you in a usual page?

Comment: Ah that could be the problem - I will try without the string class when I get a chance. Other tests (e.g. registration and login run fine)

Comment: Are you sure that there was no validation error, the `printLastResponse` is very helpful to detect this kind of stuff. Also use something like `\Log::info('Validation good')` in your store method to get some insight if the request was successful. This will log to `storage/log/laravel-YYYY-MM-DD.log`. One of the best methods for debugging ;)

Comment: Yes `printLastResponse` doesn't output anything but the url when used in `iCreateAPost()` suggesting it gets stuck somewhere around saving the post and redirecting (obviously there is no output to display prior to redirecting). I've added links to the pertinant files in my question. Will try your logging advice.

Comment: @cgross The logging advice was great. Despite no last response showing the log revealed that the database was not properly migrated (I added a field to the migration) and migrations had not rolled back. Fixed and all working

Comment: Good to hear that. There is one more tool for debugging: `dd($var)`. It's a shortcut for dump and die. And it will output pretty formatted objects/arrays in the browser and color coded in the console.